# WinSCP PUT command errors out with "Unknown switch 'rawtransfersettings'"

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

We have a job which is located in Windows server and this job is responsible for sending files to a Linux box through WinSCP utility.
We observed that file transfer process failing due to the connection error on an average every alternate day.

We are getting below error message in logs:

> Upload of file 'xxx_20190103031754.csv' was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.
>   If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp.
>    Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option.
>   General failure (server should provide error description).

In order to fix the issue I googled to set `-rawtransfersettings` for `put` command

```
open sftp://xxx@xxx.example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" -timeout=60 -rawsettings SendBuf=0 SshSimple=1

put -rawtransfersettings IgnorePermErrors=0 PreserveTimeDirs=0 "E:\Final\XXX_ASSIGNMENT_20190416200819.csv" "/<Linux Box Folder Name>/"
```

But I am getting below error

> Authenticating with pre-entered password.
>   Authenticated.
>   Starting the session...
>   Session started.
>   Active session: [1] xxx@xxx.com
>   Unknown switch 'rawtransfersettings'.

Answer (score 0):

The [`-rawtransfersettings` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#rawtransfersettings) is supported by the latest WinSCP 5.15 only. You are probably using an older version of WinSCP.

Also, if your goal was to to enable [*"Ignore permission errors"*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#upload), you need [`IgnorePermErrors=1`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#ignorepermerrors) (`0` is the default value).

*Side notes: [`PreserveTimeDirs`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#preservetimedirs) is not related to your problem and is `0` by default anyway. So you can remove that. And the double slash is suspicious, you should probably use one only.*

This should do:

```
put -rawtransfersettings IgnorePermErrors=1 "E:\Final\XXX_ASSIGNMENT_20190416200819.csv" "/"
```

---

But if your server actually does not support preserving timestamps, then you should rather use `-nopreversetime` switch. See the [documentation for the error message](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_preserve_time_perm):

> When using [scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), add [`-nopreservetime`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#nopreservetime) and [`-nopermissions`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#nopermissions) switches to [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put).

Comment: Thanks @martinprikryl